# How to make empty mfc dll project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, mfc

I have source code for existing mfc dll.
I want to create empty dll ptroject so that i can include all the source code there and modify existing dll.
Whenever i try to create mfc dll project it include few .h .def etc file it self which i don't want.
I am new in making dll please provide direction.

Comment: The easiest thing is just to delete the files you don't want... But you probably *need* that boilerplate. Creating an MFC DLL isn't the same as creating a Win32 DLL. The boilerplate ensures that you're doing it right.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an empty C++ project and set the project settings to compile to a DLL.